# Fast convert of many rows to json character

Tags: r, data.table

I have ~15 `data.frame`s with 100K-300K rows.  I want to condense on the variable `v` the other columns into a character json format for condensed storage reasons.  Note that each group in `v` will have multiple rows (1 or more; likely more).  I have code below that inefficiently uses the **jsonlite** package to convert but because of how I set up the splits it's slow and not memory efficient.  How could I do this faster and more memory efficient.  I don't need to use the **jsonlite** package just did because it's the only way I knew how to do this.  I'm thinking there's a way to make the character json directly using **data.table** in a fast way but can't think of how to do this.

***PS*** if it helps to know the motivation...I'm doing this to have a hash table that I can look up `v` in and then convert the json back to an R `data.frame` on the fly. Maybe there's a way to use **jsonlite** more directly than I am but `toJSON(dat)` is not what I'm after.

**MWE**

```
set.seed(10)

dat <- data.frame(
    v = rep(c('red', 'blue'), each =3),
    w = sample(LETTERS, 6),
    x = sample(1:3, 6, T),
    y = sample(1:3, 6, T),
    z = sample(1:3, 6, T),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

dat
```

**Data View**

```
     v w x y z
1  red N 1 1 2
2  red H 1 2 3
3  red K 2 2 3
4 blue P 2 2 2
5 blue B 2 1 3
6 blue E 2 1 2
```

**Coverting**

```
library(jsonlite)
jsonlist <- lapply(split(dat[-1], dat$v), function(x) as.character(toJSON(x)))

data.frame(
    v = names(jsonlist),
    json = unlist(jsonlist, use.names=FALSE),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

**Desired Result**

```
      v                                                                                  json
1 blue [{"w":"P","x":2,"y":2,"z":2},{"w":"B","x":2,"y":1,"z":3},{"w":"E","x":2,"y":1,"z":2}]
2  red [{"w":"N","x":1,"y":1,"z":2},{"w":"H","x":1,"y":2,"z":3},{"w":"K","x":2,"y":2,"z":3}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a data.table, you can group by `v` and pass `.SD` to `toJSON`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[, toJSON(.SD), by = v]
#      v                                                                                    V1
#1:  red [{"w":"N","x":1,"y":1,"z":2},{"w":"H","x":1,"y":2,"z":3},{"w":"K","x":2,"y":2,"z":3}]
#2: blue [{"w":"P","x":2,"y":2,"z":2},{"w":"B","x":2,"y":1,"z":3},{"w":"E","x":2,"y":1,"z":2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not convinced what you're doing makes sense, but:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(v) %>%
  do(json = select(., -v) %>% toJSON ) %>%
  mutate(json = unlist(json))
```

Comment: The `.` here doesn't do what you think it should. It seems to refer to the subset only within `do()`.

Comment: @bramtayl Do you have an alternative that would make more sense?  It's a standard lookup.  I want to have access to infor within `v` and rather than expand the data first only expand it after I have looked up `v`.  This reduces that number of rows to do the initial search considerable (from 10 million to 1  million)

Comment: I think that the edit above should work. However, I'm guessing the data.table solution will be faster.

Comment: @bramtayl I was refering to your comment that you weren't sure it makes sense.  What would make sense?

Comment: If you are using data.table, it seems like it would be easier just to keep the original dataset and set v as the key. This would make subsetting by v very fast.

Comment: Also, if you have 15 datasets with the same variables, it makes the most sense to put them together into one big dataset. You could put them into a list and use dplyr bind_rows(.id = "dataset_number") or the data.table equivalent